# How big is the chain data on a new node?

Tags: snapshots

I have been running a node for about 6 months now and my chain data recently maxed out my ssd completely and I started seeing disk I/O errors in the node's log output.

I made a mistake snapshotting, etc...and am rebuilding the node from scratch — it's currently bootstrapping.

With the new code and new node, after the bootstrapping with the chain data take under 16GB, or will it still take 150GB-ish, I'll I need to snapshot and upgrade it again?

**Update**

I should add I'm using Docker and the `mainnet.sh` script. I created a fresh node docker container (I deleted the VPS, recreated it) with the latest image and let it bootstrap. After bootstrapping I saw, I double-checked which mode I was running in:

```
$ ./mainnet.sh client rpc get /chains/main/checkpoint

{ "block":
    { "level": 442369, "proto": 3,
      "predecessor": "BLVxE1WGhVhtyFfYLDdKhe42N25nTGYWjKvfA2AokHDM6vJMjSQ",
      "timestamp": "2019-05-18T06:39:35Z", "validation_pass": 4,
      "operations_hash":
        "LLoazsHZS8KSdCNFe9B6u5y78nYCynni8tqGEACKPywmrkisE1FEz",
      "fitness": [ "00", "0000000000d35c7d" ],
      "context": "CoVCLRtu1TeX8s5BBrQ3db56epGZCx7DH6vHS6Tw7QBFzbkV3HEM",
      "protocol_data":
        "00000000000373f6f25a004b67f5443ea32df421c4dbb31b3d14bbb2b297587261e2214c69adc43157040d9578272326ea60d97eb5f01706866923f7c2b88ffe2b4dbe7e7e5901ae450300" },
  "save_point": 442369, "caboose": 0, "history_mode": "full" }
```

I checked the disk space after bootstrapping completed:

```
5.0G    store
113.9G  context
```

Then per the docs [here](https://tezos.gitlab.io/master/releases/may-2019.html#docker), I upgraded with:

`./mainnet.sh upgrade`

Now checking the disk space a day or two later or I see:

```
5.8G    store
140.7G  context
```

What is wrong here?

Is it also strange that `rpc get /chains/main/checkpoint` outputs a `proto` of 3 instead of 4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the new node in `full` history mode my bootstrapped folder looks like this:

```
store 5.5 GB 

context 13 GB
```

If you updated your node and started rebuilding the blockchain from scratch your node should be running in `full` history mode by default. There is no need to snapshot and upgrade it again.

Comment: Thanks. Things are still bootstrapping (at Feb 2019 now), and the disk space is growing at a rate in which it will run out. Currently 54.6% of 154.90GB is being used and by the time I get to 'today' the disk will be full.

After the bootstrapping is complete is there some cleanup of store and context that takes place?

Comment: Not sure about the clean-up after bootstrapping. I suggest you import from snapshot (e.g. from here: https://www.tzdutch.com/quicksync/). Make sure to delete your 'store' and 'context' folders in your .tezos-node directory before. The download file is 1.5GB-ish. Once you extracted and imported it it will be closer to 18GB but at no point in the process much higher than that.

Instructions for snapshot import: https://tezos.gitlab.io/master/releases/may-2019.html

Comment: I'm using docker a brand new container I just pulled/built (also in full mode, I double checked). Then I ran 'mainnet.sh upgrade' per the docs and my store is 5.9GB and context is 140.7G. I wonder if the docker upgrade isn't working.

Comment: You don't need to run mainnet.sh ugrade if you are already on the newest software and have no old blockchain file. Instructions following in the next comment.

Comment: Do the following: 
1. clean install a node on your machine (doesn't matter if docker or anything else; make sure your .tezos-node folder doesn't contain store and context folders)
2. download a snapshot from https://www.tzdutch.com/quicksync/ and unzip it. Instructions are in the link.
3. Navigate to unzipped file and execute command: `tezos-node snapshot import mainnet-*.full` 
4. Start node with `tezos-node run`.

Now you can execute `tezos-client bootstrapped` in a different shell and should see that the node is roughly a week behind. It will typically sync within a couple of minutes.

Comment: Thanks again. And right, mainnet.sh upgrade seems unnecessary. However, I was still huge file sizes despite having rebuilt a docker node, so I gave it a shot to no avail. The docker setup is a bit different there (eg: node data dir is in `/run/tezos/node/data`) and I don't have access to commands like tezos-node that translates to `./mainnet.sh node ...`, which only works if the container is running. But to do things cleanly I need to stop the node/container.......

Comment: Also `./mainnet.sh snapshot import mainnet-*.full` doesn't work. Whatever the hash number, docker is expecting a named volume to use which just doesn't exist. I guess if I had the ability to do a ./mainnet.sh snapshot export it would create such a volume, but using an external, arbitrary snapshot doesn't work. In the meantime, I found where the docker volumes live on the host VPS, used Choice 2 from tzdutch and copied the context and store dirs there and changed the owner and group to be correct. Now bootstrapping again and as you said, it picked up at May 29th. Fingers crossed this will work!

Comment: `ERROR: Named volume "mainnet-BMKkyoQRCUHh2nLxZE4o6q3ExQDeGntNsdMKTbzq6gEXRg6HguV.full:/snapshot:rw" is used in service "importer" but no declaration was found in the volumes section.`